# Canonical way to declare new bib2gls entries for use with glossaries-extra

Tags: package-writing, glossaries-extra, bib2gls

I found my self reusing blocks of

```latex
entry-type-aliases={%
   module = entry,%
   repo = entry,%
   ...
}
```

quite often, but I think copy pasting code is a bad idea.

As I keep reusing and expanding my glossaries, using new types and storagekeys quite regularly, I am searching for a method to create "permanent" aliases for my private types.
The creation of storage keys and setting up new styles was easily moved to dedicated packages, but with entry types I am at a loss.

MWE as per @schtandard's request:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    record={nameref},
    main,
]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{software.bib}
@software{test:software,
    name = {Test-Software},
    description = {A test software},
}
@module{test:software:module,
    name = {Test-Software-Module},
    description = {A module of \gls{test:software}},
}
\end{filecontents}


\GlsXtrLoadResources[
    src={%
            software.bib
        },% 
    entry-type-aliases={%
            software = entry,%
            module = entry,%
        },% needed for bib2gls to recognize entries
    category={same as original entry},
    type={main},
]

\begin{document}

A reference to \gls{test:software} and \gls{test:software:module}.

\printunsrtglossaries

\end{document}
```

I usually alias them to entry, but I also use a similiar mechanism to refer to recurring filenames (using a proper font for that glossary/index).
To prevent having to define the aliases for each glossary I load, I would like to define them "properly".

Comment: As is, it is unclear to me what exactly you are trying to achieve. Providing an MWE would go a long way in enabling others to understand your problem and help you.

Comment: Added an MWE @schtandard